# Mosquitto isolated users

Tags: authentication, mosquitto

Is it possible to configure mosquitto when user have the same topic name, but values will be isolated.

For example userA writes to topic "temperature"
And userB writes to topic "temperature"

userA should not see values from userB, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the topic space is shared between all users.

The best you can do is to use a ACL with a username substitution e.g.

```
pattern readwrite %u/temperature
```

This would set up a acl that allows the any user to publish/subscribe to `[username]/temperature`.

Comment: thank you, i thought that online services provide the one broker with separated user spaces

Comment: Cloud broker services may have separate topic spaces, but these are custom brokers, not mosquitto (which is the broker you asked about)

Comment: No publicly available ones that I am aware of. The concept is against the pub/sub model

Comment: could you please give me product names or services? i'll investigate it

Comment: @alexya CloudMQTT providing isolated user spaces. 
It uses mosquito as a base and looks like this service generates mount_point for every user and user messages visible only in mount point space.